# OCR without text conversion on IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, ocr

There is plenty of stuff on OCR and specifically tesseract, however not much on doing half of it. What I am trying to do is take a persons signature and convert that into a usable png image with transparency. Of course this makes OCR problematic as a signature is just a string of someones name if you convert it to text. Does anyone know of any libraries that support some sort of ocr type thing but turning it into graphics objects instead of text? Should I maybe use some sort of filters to increase contrast and subtract white as the alpha channel? Also perspective correction is fairly important. Any pointers in the right direction would help a lot! I don't know what to search for.

Thanks.

Comment: So are you trying to take a picture of a document or would they be signing on the device?

Comment: They are signing on device in most situations, however i would like to add an option to sign in pen and scan it.

Comment: No point on using OCR on signatures. Because OCR is for recognizing characters. If you just need the signature on clear background, you can do that with image processing alone.

Comment: Ok i'll look into that then. The part i'm concerned about is how clean the background removal would be and the perspective correction.